# datepart some months from 2 years

Tags: sql

I have this code:

```
SELECT Jmeno, COUNT(Ucast)
  FROM Hraci
 INNER JOIN Ucast_Zapas ON Ucast_Zapas.ID_Hrace_zapas=Hraci.IDHrace
 INNER JOIN Zapas ON Zapas.ID_zapas=Ucast_Zapas.ID_zapasu_ucast
 INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Zapas.Kategorie_zapas
 WHERE (Ucast=1)
   AND (Kategorie.IDkategorie=1)
   AND (datepart(year, Zapas_Datum) = '2013')
   AND (datepart(MONTH, Zapas_Datum) BETWEEN 1 AND 5) 
GROUP BY Jmeno;
```

What i want write, when i want 8.-12.month year 2013 and 1.-8.month year 2014?

Comment: The code is clear.  The question afterwards is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your requirements correct, you want to return all records whose ZAPAS_Datum field is between 8/2013 and 8/2014?  If so, then this should work:

```
SELECT Jmeno, COUNT(Ucast)
  FROM Hraci
 INNER JOIN Ucast_Zapas ON Ucast_Zapas.ID_Hrace_zapas=Hraci.IDHrace
 INNER JOIN Zapas ON Zapas.ID_zapas=Ucast_Zapas.ID_zapasu_ucast
 INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Zapas.Kategorie_zapas
 WHERE (Ucast=1)
   AND (Kategorie.IDkategorie=1)
   AND Zapas_Datum >= '8/1/2013' 
   AND Zapas_Datum < '9/1/2014' 
GROUP BY Jmeno;
```

BTW -- Depending on your RDBMS, you may need to format your date differently than above.